# How do I create multiple children for a single parent in FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby, testing, factory-bot

## What we want to achieve

I am using FactoryBot to create test data, and when I create a parent in create_list, I want to create 5 children for each parent, is this possible? What should I do in this case?

## Code

Book is a parent.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book, class: Post do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n}
    sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
    sequence(:author) { |n| "author#{n}" }
    sequence(:image) { |n| "image#{n}"}
  end
end
```

The content is the children

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :content, class: PostItem do
    sequence(:content) { |n| "list#{n}"}
    sequence(:status) { false }  
  end
end
```

I want to make five children for each parent.

Five children can be created for each parent.

```
book = FactoryBot.create(:book)

content = FactoryBot.create_list(:contet, 5, post_id: book.id)
```

For multiple parents, I don't know how to create five children for one parent.

```
book = FactoryBot.create_list(:book)
content = FactoryBot.create_list(:contet, 5, post_id: ???)
```

Comment: Have you tried `book.each {|b| FactoryBot.create_list(:contet, 5, post_id: b.id)}`?

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. I didn't do it. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to generalize this would be to use after hooks in your factory.

For instance you could do the following :

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book, class: Post do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n}
    sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
    sequence(:author) { |n| "author#{n}" }
    sequence(:image) { |n| "image#{n}"}
    
    # trait is optional, but nice to have. Call it with FactoryBot.create :book, :with_content
    trait :with_content do
      after(:create) do |object|
        FactoryBot.create_list(:content, 5, post_id: object.id)
        object.reload # to reload the association. You could avoid the reload by using your association (ie: object.contents = ...)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or a simplier version

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book, class: Post do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n}
    sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
    sequence(:author) { |n| "author#{n}" }
    sequence(:image) { |n| "image#{n}"}
    
    after(:create) do |object|
      object.posts = FactoryBot.create_list(:content, 5)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't know much about traits and afters, so I was hesitant to use them. I also don't understand the object.reload you suggested, I don't know what good it does to add reload. I'm sorry. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have added a simplified version. `traits` would be relevant if you need to be able to create books without content sometimes. The `reload` was to ensure it works event if you didn't have a `has_many :contents` on your `Book` model